# looping through nested arrays and accessing elements RUBY

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I want to iterate through a nested array and operate on each element, so square each number in this case. I know how to do it for a normal array but for some reason i am getting undefined map method when include deeper iteration to access the inner arrays. Am a newbie too so if you could explain how it works that would help my learning. Thanks

```
def SquareArrayElements(n)
  n.each do |number|
    number.map do |num|
     squared_nums = num * num
  end
end
squared_nums  
end
SquareArrayElements([10,[[10],10],[10]])
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output for the input above?

Comment: i want to square the 10s and return them to one array =>[100,100,100,100]. Can you let me know what I need to do please Sara?

Comment: This is a task i have been set to learn to iterate through nested arrays. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since you've said in the comments that:

> i want to square the 10s and return them to one array =>[100,100,100,100].

I assume that you don't need to preserve the original arrays and just want one array with the squared results. If that's the case you can [`#flatten`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten) the array and then square the numbers:

```
def square_array(arr)
  arr.flatten.map { |e| e ** 2 }
end  

square_array([10,[[10],10],[10]])
#=> [100, 100, 100, 100]
```

Comment: Good solution!  I don't think this is what OP wants, based on his comments he needs to demonstrate iteration.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, i tried your solution and it works, i fear i will get told that i cheated because i have shown no working out lol. I need to show looping through the nested arrays without complex code. I will keep this code for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to call map on the arrays, not on the integers.  That's why you're getting an undefined map method, integers don't support that method.

Try

```
def square_array(element)
  if element.responds_to?(:map)
    element.map{|m| square_array(m)}
  else
    element * element
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, is there a way to do it using my code? I ask because that's roughly what the coach said i had to do to iterate deeper into nested arrays. Thanks again. I am yet to learn responds_to?().

Comment: `Iteration` means repetition of a process... in Ruby it usually means a method that calls itself until it reaches a condition where it doesn't need to call itself.  Your coach (I would guess) is expecting you to have `my_method` call `my_method` again on the nested arrays, until it reaches the integer.  Instead of `responds_to?` you can do `kind_of?(Array)` -- did you learn `kind_of?`

Comment: i only know is_a?(). is this similar to kind_of?() and responds_to?() ?, i will look these up anyway. Final question so the best way to iterate through any nested array is calling the method within like your example Steve?

Comment: You can always consult the [docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/kind_of%3F)

Comment: Yes, `is_a?` would work. Generally if you need to handle nested arrays in arrays, then you would call the method again within the method and that's called `recursion`.  But you need to ensure there is some exit mechanism, testing if you need to continue the `recursion`.  If you don't, you can get a "stack overflow" :)